# How to filter the contacts who has hit the persona on specific page

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics, user-profile

Suppose, we have two pages one with the content relevant to Microsoft and one with content relevant to Apple. I have applied for two profile cards, one on the Microsoft page and one on the Apple page.

Now, I want to filter the logged-in users (based on a custom profile property, say company name) who have hit my pages with either Microsoft or apple profile cards.

This I want to be simple so that the marketing person can go to Sitecore and see the data as per the filter requirements like who are the users with custom profile property **company name**.

In summary: How to know logged-in users hitting a specific profile card page?

Environment: Habitat on Sitecore 9.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to know that the Sitecore Segmentation list is useful for this task. If your experience analytics is all set with proper configurations then it will track which contact has hit which profile card pages.

You can go to the segmentation lists and apply the rule to match the pattern card for the contacts and then that will give you the filtered list as per the rule.

I used the following rule for the segmentation:

[image]

For filtering on the basis of the custom property you will be required to create a custom segmentation rule and then you can use that rule in addition to the one shown in the screenshot below.